# How can we schedule our commits and merges?

Tags: git

I am just a newbie at git.

I was just analysing the idea of building an automated tool for code versioning and code deployment as a side project in Selenium and Jenkins. For that, I am thinking of scalability of this tool and how it can be used at commercial level like in offices and with every project based on their custom config and project profiling.

Then, the following questions popped up in my head for which I am still researching about:

1. Is it possible to schedule commits to the local branch by setting a custom schedule?
2. How can we fetch the status of all the pending PRs, and when they are merged, automated builds can be scheduled based on the new commits in the master branch of the repository? Or do we have to associate the builds to the PRs?
3. Is it a good idea to have scheduled merges?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to schedule *commits*? What should those contain? Don't you want to schedule *builds*? Why schedule merging? Branches should be merged when they are ready to merge, not based on some timing (unless you want to automatically merge master into your PR, which seems like a dangerous thing to do=.

Comment: To answer your questions: No, there's nothing built into git to schedule commits on a regular basis. You *can* do it using the normal scheduling tools of your operating systems, but I would advise against it. As for automating builds, jenkins, teamcity, etc. can easily be set up to watch branches and fetch and build when new commits appear on them. As for "is it a good idea", my opinion is no, but this likely makes the question likely to be closed as "Primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @JoachimSauer I am just experimenting a trial repo, just for the learning part. Maybe I will learn to solve a difficult issue this way. Just like a playtime side project activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merges and commits are something that needs human review. There are CI/CD pipelines that can take care of things after every commit or every merge, but as far the actual merging goes, it should be done manually by a developer, preferably after code reviews.

Commits refer to logical chunks of work: fixing a bug, adding a feature, changing the theme etc., these things don't work on a delta of time but on the delta of output of the developer.

Comment: Abishek is right, you should build you ci/cd around human actions. Human should only have to do a minimal set of things. but everything else should be triggered by human action. To attach action to a certain time or time span is counterproductive.